# replaceWith() jQuery not work on server 2012

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-server-2012, replacewith

```
<ul class="slides">

<span id="icerikcontainer_slider">

<li><div class="img"><img alt="'Yeni Efesliler' Açıldı" src="upl/2013916428547451.jpg" /></div><div class="caption"><h2>'Yeni Efesliler' Açıldı</h2><p>Yeni Efesliler Sergisi
bağlı iletişim, eğitim, araştırma ve kültür merkezi  olarak 2012 yılında eski tütün deposunda açılan Selçuk Efes Kent Belleği Merkezi,</p><p class="more"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="manset.aspx?id=6">Devamı</a></p></div></li>   

<li><div class="img"><img alt="Geçmiş Bugün İle Buluştu" src="upl/201391644901121.JPG" /></div><div class="caption"><h2>Geçmiş Bugün İle Buluştu</h2><p>Geçtiğimiz yıl 4 Eylül'de kapılarını ziyaretçilere açan"Yeni Efesliler" sergisi ile bir kez daha vatandaşlar ile buluştu.</p><p class="more"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="manset.aspx?id=3">Devamı</a></p></div></li> 

</span>
</ul>        

<script type="text/javascript">
var e = document.getElementById('ctl00_icerikcontainer_slider').innerHTML;
$(".slides").replaceWith('<ul class="slides">'+e+'</ul>');
</script>
```

---

Script in server 2008 is running. Server 2012 does not work.

Example :
[server 2008](http://selcukefeskentbellegi.com)  , [server 2012](http://gezinen.com)

Comment: where is the element `ctl00_icerikcontainer_slider`

Comment: also try to move the code to a dom ready handler

Comment: There is no reason why the server operating system should affect the client-side code. There must be something different in the way the pages appear to the browser: you need to work out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ctl00_icerikcontainer_slider` in your page. It looks like a server-assigned id so I think your `<span id="icerikcontainer_slider">` should be `<span runat="server" id="icerikcontainer_slider">` and then you could use

```
var e = document.getElementById('<%=icerikcontainer_slider.ClientID %>').innerHTML;
```

You can find more info about ASP.Net inline expressions at http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx